# Related to FCM Push Notification

Tags: php, android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

```js
<?php 
//$tokenkey=$_POST['tokenkey'];
$tokenkey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
if(isset($tokenkey)){
   $API_ACCESS_KEY="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
               $registrationIds = array( $tokenkey);
               // prep the bundle
    $msg = array
    (
     'message'  => 'This is Driver Message',
     'title'  => 'This is a title. title',
     'subtitle' => 'This is a subtitle.subtitle',
     'tickerText' => 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
     'vibrate' => 1,
     'sound'  => 1,
     'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
     'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
    );
    $fields = array
    (
     'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds ,
     'data'   => $msg
    );
     
    $headers = array
    (
     'Authorization: key=' . $API_ACCESS_KEY,
     'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
     //https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
//https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields) );
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
                                echo "\r\n res:  ".$result;
     if ($result === FALSE) {
      die('Failed: ' . curl_error($ch) . "\r\n");
     } else {
       $message = ['message' =>'Success'];
      echo json_encode($message);  
     }
    curl_close( $ch );
}

?>
```

[image]On using all api keys like android key, browser key, server key, I am getting invalid (legacy) server key reponse.. Error 401 using php code. I have implemented firebase class and google-servcice.json file properly. And can send push message from Firebase console app. But Using php I am getting  invalid (legacy) server key reponse. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do post relevant code snippets

Comment: Please look at this.. I have edited..

Comment: once check it in console using this link   http://apns-gcm.bryantan.info/

Comment: Are you using the Server Key or the Legacy Server Key for your `API_ACCESS_KEY`? Also, are you positive that the registration token you're sending the message to is associated with the project the message is coming from (Sender ID)?

Comment: I am using Server Key.  This server key is present under FCM setting under permission.

Comment: Anything else i need to do in firebase?

Comment: Hi. What do you mean under **Permissions**? The Server Key that you need to use is supposed to be the one visible in **Project Settings** > **Cloud Messaging** tab.